# Draw crosshairs on the screen - ZedGraph

Tags: c#, optimization

Here's some part of my code is use to draw objects on the screen :

#### Class members:

```
private double cursorX = 0;
private double cursorY = 0;
private LineObj cursorOldY = new LineObj();
private LineObj cursorOldX = new LineObj();
private int index1 = 0;

private double cursor2X = 0;
private double cursor2Y = 0;
private LineObj cursor2OldY = new LineObj();
private LineObj cursor2OldX = new LineObj();
private int index2 = -1;

ZedGraph.CurveItem curve = null;
```

#### Drawing function :

```
private void drawCursors(bool first, bool second, bool fromKeyboard = false, Point mousePoint = new Point()) 
{
    GraphPane p = lineGraphControl1.GraphPane;
    if (p.CurveList.Count == 0 || curve == null)
        return;

    ZedGraph.Axis axis = curve.IsY2Axis ? (Axis)p.Y2AxisList[curve.YAxisIndex] : (Axis)p.YAxisList[curve.YAxisIndex];
    ZedGraph.PointPair point = new PointPair(0.0, 0.0);
    if (first)
    {
        p.GraphObjList.Remove(cursorOldY);
        p.GraphObjList.Remove(cursorOldX);
        if (fromKeyboard)
           point = curve.Points[index1];
        else if (lineGraphControl1.Graph.XAxis.Mode == XAxisMode.Parameter)
        {
            ZedGraph.CurveItem outputCurve;
            p.FindNearestPoint(mousePoint, curve, out outputCurve, out index1);
            if (index1 >= 0)
               point = curve.Points[index1];
        }
        else
        {
           if (!mousePoint.IsEmpty)
               p.ReverseTransform(mousePoint, out cursorX, out cursorY);
           point = findPoint(curve, cursorX);
        }
        cursorX = point.X;
        cursorY = transform(point.Y, axis);
        cursorOldY = new LineObj(cursorX, p.YAxis.Scale.Min, cursorX, p.YAxis.Scale.Max);
        cursorOldX = new LineObj(p.XAxis.Scale.Max, cursorY, p.XAxis.Scale.Min, cursorY);

       if (cursorX > p.XAxis.Scale.Min && cursorX < p.XAxis.Scale.Max)
           p.GraphObjList.Add(cursorOldY);

       if (cursorY > p.YAxis.Scale.Min && cursorY < p.YAxis.Scale.Max)
           p.GraphObjList.Add(cursorOldX);
   }
   if (second)
   {
       p.GraphObjList.Remove(cursor2OldY);
       p.GraphObjList.Remove(cursor2OldX);
       if (fromKeyboard)
           point = curve.Points[index2];
       else if (lineGraphControl1.Graph.XAxis.Mode == XAxisMode.Parameter)
       {
           ZedGraph.CurveItem outputCurve;
           p.FindNearestPoint(mousePoint, curve, out outputCurve, out index2);
           if (index2 >= 0)
               point = curve.Points[index2];
       }
       else
       {
           if (!mousePoint.IsEmpty)
               p.ReverseTransform(mousePoint, out cursor2X, out cursor2Y);
           point = findPoint(curve, cursor2X);
           if (index2 == -1)
           {
               index2 = (int) Math.Round(curve.NPts * 0.75, 0);
               point = curve.Points[index2];
           }
       }

       cursor2X = point.X;
       cursor2Y = transform(point.Y, axis);
       cursor2OldY = new LineObj(cursor2X, p.YAxis.Scale.Min, cursor2X, p.YAxis.Scale.Max);
       cursor2OldX = new LineObj(p.XAxis.Scale.Max, cursor2Y, p.XAxis.Scale.Min, cursor2Y);

       if (cursor2X > p.XAxis.Scale.Min && cursor2X < p.XAxis.Scale.Max)
           p.GraphObjList.Add(cursor2OldY);
       if (cursor2Y > p.YAxis.Scale.Min && cursor2Y < p.YAxis.Scale.Max)
           p.GraphObjList.Add(cursor2OldX);
    }
}
```

Is (structurally speaking) there some optimizations I missed ?

Comment: How is `drawCursors` called? And by what?

Comment: @NickUdell it is called in different places with different parameters depending on the user input. The only thing that will always be true is that `(first || second) = true`

Comment: It must, surely, only be called inside that class though, as it's private. Give us some examples from within that class?

Comment: @NickUdell if the user moves the mouse, the function is called with `drawCursors(true, false, false, Mouse.Position)`

Comment: [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: At your class variables you have made 2 section with 5 variables. What does one section represent ?

Comment: @Heslacher it's all the variables I need to draw one crosshair (the user can display one or two crosshair, not more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DRY Don't repeat yourself**

Looking at the method, it is clearly seen that you do the same thing for `first == true` and for `second == true`, but you are using different variables.

As the set of variables

> ```
> private double cursor2X = 0;
> private double cursor2Y = 0;
> private LineObj cursor2OldY = new LineObj();
> private LineObj cursor2OldX = new LineObj();
> private int index2 = -1;
> ```

are defining, what you need to draw a `crosshair`, you should place them inside a class.

An instance of this class can then be passed instead of the bool first,second to your method. In this way you have less code to maintain, if e.g something should be changed in this drawing part, as you only need to change it once and not twice.

**Naming**

> ```
> GraphPane p
> ```

Single letter variable names should be avoided. For loops as iteration variable they are ok, or for positioning like x,y. Your code would be easier to understand if you would name it `pane` instead.

Based on the [naming guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you should use `PascalCasing` casing for method names.

Answer (score 5):

Mis-Matching curly braces are not a good thing, you do it all over the place, it makes your code hard to read

> ```
>    if (fromKeyboard)
>        point = curve.Points[index1];
>     else if (lineGraphControl1.Graph.XAxis.Mode == XAxisMode.Parameter)
>     {
>         ZedGraph.CurveItem outputCurve;
>         p.FindNearestPoint(mousePoint, curve, out outputCurve, out index1);
>         if (index1 >= 0)
>            point = curve.Points[index1];
>     }
>     else
>     {
> ```

it should look like this

```
   if (fromKeyboard)
   {
       point = curve.Points[index1];
   }
   else if (lineGraphControl1.Graph.XAxis.Mode == XAxisMode.Parameter)
   {
        ZedGraph.CurveItem outputCurve;
        p.FindNearestPoint(mousePoint, curve, out outputCurve, out index1);
        if (index1 >= 0)
           point = curve.Points[index1];
   }
   else
   {
```

Indentation only on an if statement all by itself is fine, I personally don't like it, but when an else statement is added to the if statement, it starts to muddy the waters around your if statement and make it look sloppy.

---

The single, one-line if statements should also have a buffer zone after them as well.

Comment: You're right, I'll change it

Comment: don't edit it into the question. when you get some good constructive answers, clean up your code and post a follow-up question.

Comment: Do you mean that I should post another question after you answer ? I'm not sure to understand you well...

Comment: I posted a link in the comments on your question. when you get more answers, change the code on your local machine, make sure it works and post another question with it.

Comment: Ok, I'll read your link. I like this site :)